# CSS transforn: scale apply only big images

Tags: css

Currently I am trying to scale all images wider than 960px down.

Applying css code works correctly:

```
.images {
  transform: scale(.5)
};
```

and it scales images down to be .5 of size.

Is it possible to scale images based on the image size, eg:

```
@media ??? ( min-width: 960px ) {
  .images {
    transform: scale(.5)
  }
}
```

Couldn't find any correct media type, is there any way achieving my goal using only css?

Comment: You just want to scale all those images down _by half_? That is a rather unusual case, can’t see much of a point in that? Normally people apply a `max-width` to scale images down to a _common_ maximum width. But anyway, a media query for “original image width” does not really exist in the first place.

Comment: media queries work with screen width not on element's width so I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: I have a modal with ability uploading images, so if they are wider wanted to make them smaller regardless on the screen size

Comment: one thing that I supposed you could do is to set an attribute like "data-big" to those images with big size and then select them with "Attribute Selectors
" in your css:

Comment: this requires some validation upon uploading, wanted to do with css "validation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 50% percentage value for `width`, combined with `height: auto` (for keeping the proportion – or the other way round, depending on the situation), a `min-width` pixel value (in order to apply the percentage only above a certain width) and optionally a `max-width` pixel value to define an absolute limit for the image sizes.